# memcache transactions and concurency

Tags: php, concurrency, locking, memcached

I have a very strange problem with using memcache, php, locks and concurrent queries. Please take a look on main function:

```
class memcachedata {

public function getdata($key,$params) {
        $timeout = 3600;
        $mem = $this->memcache;
        $expiry = $mem->get(md5($key.$params.'_lock'));
        $this->log('GET EXPIRY');
        if ($expiry) {
           $data   = $mem->get(md5($key));
           $this->log('DATA GET');
        } else
        {
           $this->log('SET LOCK');
       $mem->set(md5($key.$params.'_lock'),'locked',$timeout);
           $data = $this->calculate_external_data($key,$params);//curl here
           if ($data) {
               $mem->set(md5($key.$params),$data,$timeout);
               $this->log('DATA UPDATED'); 
               }
        }
    return $data;
}
}
```

DEBUG INFO:

```
00:00:00 GET EXPIRY
00:00:00 GET DATA
00:00:00 GET EXPIRY
00:00:00 SET LOCK
00:00:00 DATA UPDATED
00:00:01 GET EXPIRY
00:00:01 GET DATA
```

This is proper result.

Problem is when this function is being called multiple times from other functions or by multiple users in one(or) separate session like:

```
function getuserinfo($username,$message){
return $this->getdata('users',"'$username','$message'");
}
```

DEBUG INFO:

```
00:00:00 GET EXPIRY
00:00:00 SET LOCK
00:00:00 DATA UPDATED
00:00:00 GET EXPIRY
00:00:00 SET LOCK
00:00:00 DATA UPDATED
00:00:03 GET EXPIRY
00:00:03 SET LOCK
00:00:03 DATA UPDATED
```

Why function getdata does not see a lock? Is it a time to start using MQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was with php7.0 and was using old memcache extension. Moving to memcached solved this problem. How? I do not know.